# jQuery Mobile Panel Problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, cordova

I have a jQuery Mobile Panel that's not behaving properly (in PhoneGap if the matters).

```
<div data-role="panel" id="nav-popup-menu" data-position="left" data-transition="slide" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="true">
  <button class="search">Search</button>
</div>

.ui-panel {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
  width: 200px;
}

<a href="#nav-popup-menu" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" style="background-color: #f6f5f4; border-color: #f6f5f4; color: #f6f5f4; ">|</a>
```

Based on the above I would expect that pressing anywhere outside the panel would cause it to close. However, this behavior doesn't seem to respect my custom width. That is, if I press at 250px, it doesn't close, whereas if I press at 500px, where the default width would have already ended, it does close.

Using JQM 1.4.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Panel* adds an overlay with class `ui-panel-dismiss`, which closes active *panel* once clicked/touched. The default position of the panel's overlay is `left: 17em;` (in case of left panel). That value also represents the default width of panel.

When you override *panel*'s width, you also need to adjust overlay's position. Just give it the same value of *panel*'s new width.

```
.ui-panel-dismiss {
  left: 200px !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/EKNXv/)**