# Disable background page when panel is open - jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I disable the background page (#page3) when the jQM slide panel (#panel3) is open? I don't want to be able to click outside the panel to close it, nor listen to any events on the background page.

```
$("#page3").prop("disabled", true);  // not working
$("#page3").page("disable");         // not working



<div data-role="panel" id="panel3" data-display="overlay" data-dismissible="false">
   <h3>Foo</h3>
   // stuff
   <form></form>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using dismissible panel?

Comment: No just an overlay panel... can it be set to have 100% control?

Comment: I meant when you click outside the panel, does it close by itself, or you use a _close_ button?

Comment: I use data-dismissible="false" ;-) But it's still possible to click on the background. The panel doesnt close

Comment: use `panelopen` event to add a transparent overlay equals to panel's height and positioned to cover the visible part of page. Check the demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302978/jquery-mobile-panel-problems/22305216#22305216) but this is for dismissible panel, just do the same ;)

Comment: Ah, yes that is probably the easiest solution :-)